# Can't install Jetstream package to Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I use Laravel 8 framework. PHP version is 7.4. After running command

```
composer require laravel/jetstream
```

I have some errors:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
> packages.
>
> Problem 1
> - laravel/jetstream 1.x-dev requires laravel/fortify ^1.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/fortify[1.x-dev, v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.1.0,
> v1.2.0, v1.2.1, v1.3.0, v1.3.1, v1.4.0, v1.4.1, v1.4.2, v1.4.3,
> v1.5.0, v1.6.0, v1.6.1, v1.6.2].
> - laravel/jetstream v1.5.0 requires laravel/fortify ^1.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/fortify[1.x-dev, v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.1.0,
> v1.2.0, v1.2.1, v1.3.0, v1.3.1, v1.4.0, v1.4.1, v1.4.2, v1.4.3,
> v1.5.0, v1.6.0, v1.6.1, v1.6.2].
> - laravel/jetstream v1.5.1 requires laravel/fortify ^1.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/fortify[1.x-dev, v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.1.0,
> v1.2.0, v1.2.1, v1.3.0, v1.3.1, v1.4.0, v1.4.1, v1.4.2, v1.4.3,
> v1.5.0, v1.6.0, v1.6.1, v1.6.2].
> - laravel/fortify 1.x-dev requires bacon/bacon-qr-code ^2.0 -> satisfiable by bacon/bacon-qr-code[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2].
> - laravel/fortify v1.0.0 requires bacon/bacon-qr-code ^2.0 -> satisfiable by bacon/bacon-qr-code[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2].
> - laravel/fortify v1.0.1 requires bacon/bacon-qr-code ^2.0 -> satisfiable by bacon/bacon-qr-code[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2].
> - laravel/fortify v1.1.0 requires bacon/bacon-qr-code ^2.0 -> satisfiable by bacon/bacon-qr-code[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2].
> - laravel/fortify v1.2.0 requires bacon/bacon-qr-code ^2.0 -> satisfiable by bacon/bacon-qr-code[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2].
> - laravel/fortify v1.2.1 requires bacon/bacon-qr-code ^2.0 -> satisfiable by bacon/bacon-qr-code[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2].
> - laravel/fortify v1.3.0 requires bacon/bacon-qr-code ^2.0 -> satisfiable by bacon/bacon-qr-code[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2].
> - laravel/fortify v1.3.1 requires bacon/bacon-qr-code ^2.0 -> satisfiable by bacon/bacon-qr-code[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2].
> - laravel/fortify v1.4.0 requires bacon/bacon-qr-code ^2.0 -> satisfiable by bacon/bacon-qr-code[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2].
> - laravel/fortify v1.4.1 requires bacon/bacon-qr-code ^2.0 -> satisfiable by bacon/bacon-qr-code[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2].
> - laravel/fortify v1.4.2 requires bacon/bacon-qr-code ^2.0 -> satisfiable by bacon/bacon-qr-code[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2].
> - laravel/fortify v1.4.3 requires bacon/bacon-qr-code ^2.0 -> satisfiable by bacon/bacon-qr-code[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2].
> - laravel/fortify v1.5.0 requires bacon/bacon-qr-code ^2.0 -> satisfiable by bacon/bacon-qr-code[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2].
> - laravel/fortify v1.6.0 requires bacon/bacon-qr-code ^2.0 -> satisfiable by bacon/bacon-qr-code[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2].
> - laravel/fortify v1.6.1 requires bacon/bacon-qr-code ^2.0 -> satisfiable by bacon/bacon-qr-code[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2].
> - laravel/fortify v1.6.2 requires bacon/bacon-qr-code ^2.0 -> satisfiable by bacon/bacon-qr-code[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2].
> - bacon/bacon-qr-code 2.0.2 requires ext-iconv * -> the requested PHP extension iconv is missing from your system.
> - bacon/bacon-qr-code 2.0.1 requires ext-iconv * -> the requested PHP extension iconv is missing from your system.
> - bacon/bacon-qr-code 2.0.0 requires ext-iconv * -> the requested PHP extension iconv is missing from your system.
> - Installation request for laravel/jetstream ^1.5 -> satisfiable by laravel/jetstream[1.x-dev, v1.5.0, v1.5.1].
>
> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini
> files:
> - /etc/php/php.ini
> - /etc/php/conf.d/igbinary.ini
> - /etc/php/conf.d/redis.ini   You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
> content.

I have read some manuals, but I didn't see similar errors. Please, help.

Comment: From `/php/ini.php` file uncomment this line `ext=iconv` then restart you server again

Comment: It boils down to `the requested PHP extension iconv is missing from your system.`. Install the iconv php extension, and it should hopefully work

Comment: Oh... thanks!!! I will read the console more carefully in the future!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to enable the extension iconv from the file `'etc/php/ini.php'` by uncommenting the line where `extension= iconv`, I'm not sure about the path of the file in Windows and Mac Os since I use Linux